# How can I make a hyperlink open as a popup with a given width and height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a hyperlink that is:

```
 <a href="some.html">Test</a>
```

If I click on the Test link, `some.html` should open as pop up menu with some given width & height.

How can I do this?

Comment: are you actually looking for a "popup" or just a menu that appears on the same page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `target='_blank'` sometimes opens in a new tab, and it usually does for Firefox and Chrome. Your best best is to use Frédéric's code:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('some.html', 'yourWindowName', 'width=200,height=150');">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use [window.open()](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml):

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('some.html', 'yourWindowName', 'width=200,height=150');">Test</a>
```

Or:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('some.html', 'yourWindowName', 'width=200,height=150');">Test</a>
```

Comment: How can we make the popup to display at the center of the window.Currently, it is opening extreme top left of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

To open in popup, you can use `target="_blank"`:

```
<a href="some.html" target="_blank">Test</a>
```

Or use [`window.open`](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml):

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('some.html', 'win', 'width=400,height="400"')">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

easy way to implement without the anchor element and without the new popup window toolbar

```
<span class="popup" onClick="javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank','toolbar=no,width=250,height=250');">
```

Comment: For some reason, using the javascript in the href attribute of the anchor element didn't work for me when my page was external and using a full url with domain name. The onClick attribute worked better for me in this case, but I still used an anchor element.

Answer (score 1):

Try use this code :

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open('yourLink','_blank','width=900,height=300');">Try</a>
```

Using `javascript: void(0)` to make no any contact of previous page after you click popup window.